# Criar estruturas dinâmicas partindo de um ficheiro de texto?

Tags: c, arquivo, lista, estrutura-de-dados

Eu tenho dados guardados num ficheiro texto. Quero ler o ficheiro texto e armazenar os dados em variáveis minhas, para depois inseri-los na minha função `inserir_medico` que vai usar os dados para criar uma Lista concatenada.
O problema é que, eu tenho uma variável que conta o numero de "medicos", esta variável no final do programa devia ser igual a 3 (`conta_med = 3`), pois eu tenho apenas 3 medicos no meu ficheiro (com as respectivas especialidades e horas de entrada e de saída).

Gostaria de saber porque é que no final eu recebo `conta_med = 5` e não `conta_med = 3`? Será que é por estar a trabalhar com um ficheiro texto e não binário?

O conteúdo do ficheiro texto é:

> Joao Silva
>
> Neurologia 9.30 - 17.00
>
> Ana Maria Santos
>
> Pediatria 10.00 - 19.00
>
> Sandra Almeida
>
> Dermatologia 14.00 - 17.45

Função que vai buscar os dados do ficheiro para colocar nos elementos da lista:

```
int med_ficheiro(){

    FILE *fm;  char mnome[50], esp[50]; int h_entrada, h_saida;
    int conta_med=0;
    int linhas[100], z=0, x=0;
    char ch;
    inic_med();

        fm= fopen("medicos.txt","r");
        if(fm==NULL){
            printf("Impossivel abrir o ficheiro.\n");
            exit(1);
        }


         else{
        printf("\n\n\n");
        while(!feof(fm)){

           fgets(mnome,50,fm);

           fscanf(fm,"%s %f - %f", esp, &h_entrada, &h_saida);

           inserir_medico(mnome, esp, h_entrada, h_saida);
           conta_med++;



        } 
         printf("%d", conta_med); //AQUI DÁ ERRADO!!! PORQUE??? (MOSTRA "5")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O `while(!feof(fm))` está errado (ver [esta pergunta no SO em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)).

O que acontece é que a função `feof()` não indica se a próxima leitura vai dar erro, ela indica se o último erro foi devido ao ficheiro estar no fim.

Mais uma coisa: não mistures leituras com `fgets()` e `fscanf()`. É preferível ler sempre com `fgets()` e interpretar a linha com `sscanf()` de seguida.

A maneira correcta (com algumas validações adicionadas) é

```
    while (fgets(mnome, sizeof mnome, fm)) {    // primeira linha
        // remover ENTER de mnome
        size_t mnomelen = strlen(mnome);
        if (mnome[mnonelen - 1] == '\n') {
            mnome[--mnomelen] = 0;
        }
        char temp[100];
        // segunda linha
        if (fgets(temp, sizeof temp, fm) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Erro na leitura da segunda linha\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (sscanf(temp, "%49s%f -%f", esp, &h_entrada, &h_saida) != 3) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Erro na interpretação da 2a linha\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        inserir_medico(mnome, esp, h_entrada, h_saida);
        conta_med++;
    }
```